# Redundancy in excel data validation formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm working on a large old and clunky excel spreadsheet, currently using excel 2007. I've come across the following interesting formula for data validation on a particular cell

```
=IF($B36="CMD Account Team",
    ACCTEmployeeName,
 IF($B36="ITS",
    UnknownEmployeeName,
    UnknownEmployeeName))
```

That second if is very strange. Isn't the above formula equivalent to

```
=IF($B36="CMD Account Team",
    ACCTEmployeeName,
    UnknownEmployeeName)
```

And what reason could the original author have had for the redundancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a *nested if* statement. The second `IF` is what the formula evaluates when the first `IF` returns false.  I think you have a handle on this, but I am posting explanation so that others who might have a similar question can understand what's happening.

`If($B36="CMD Accoutn Team",`

If this evaluates True, then the function returns the value for `ACCTEmployeeName`.  However, if this function returns False, i.e., `$B36 <> "CMD Account Team"`, then the formula evaluates a second `IF`.

You're correct, that you could simplify the formula, with no apparent errors, to:

`=IF($B36="CMD Account Team",
    ACCTEmployeeName,
    UnknownEmployeeName)`

> **And what reason could the original author have had for the redundancy?**

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say one of two things:

- The formula was written with some other condition(s) originally, and at some point it was changed by someone who either didn't know, or simply wasn't paying close enough attention to notice the redundancy.
- The formula was written incorrectly, and one or the other of `UnknownEmployeeName` should refer to another Name/variable.